# Replace nested if-clauses with some kind of table thingy

Tags: java

I want to make a simple small awt.component, that gives me a resize cursor on all 4 edges (as well as the 4 corners) and a movement cursor in the "body" of the component.

The following code works but looks kind of ugly and complex for such a simple task.

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if (interactMode != InteractivityMode.EDIT_WINDOW){
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        return;
    }

    // left border
    if (arg0.getX() < RESCALE_AREA) {
        if (arg0.getY() < RESCALE_AREA) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        } else if(arg0.getY() > getHeight()-RESCALE_AREA) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        } else {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        }
    // right border
    } else if (arg0.getX() > getWidth() - RESCALE_AREA) {
        if (arg0.getY() < RESCALE_AREA) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        } else if(arg0.getY() > getHeight()-RESCALE_AREA) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        } else {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
        }
    // top border
    } else if (arg0.getY() < RESCALE_AREA) {
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
    // bottom border
    } else if (arg0.getY() > getHeight()-RESCALE_AREA) {
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR));
    // cursor not on the border
    } else {
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }

}
```

**Can this be done in a shorter/clearer/better way?**

Is there maybe some kind of "truth table" thingy that allows me write something more human readable and failproof like:

```
X < RA | X > w-RA | Y < RA | Y > h-RA | result
----------------------------------------------
  y    |   n      |  y     |  n       | NW cursor
  y    |   n      |  n     |  n       | W cursor
  y    |   n      |  n     |  y       | SW cursor
  n    |   y      |  y     |  n       | NE cursor
  n    |   y      |  n     |  n       | E cursor
  n    |   y      |  n     |  y       | SE cursor
  n    |   n      |  y     |  n       | N cursor
  n    |   n      |  n     |  n       | movement cursor
  n    |   n      |  n     |  y       | S cursor
```

---

**Bonus:** It seems to me, that the above code is executed (in theory) whenever I move my mousecursor even only a single pixel. This seems like quite a bit of calculation power.. Is there another way of doing this, or should I simply stop worrying and leave it all to hands of the awt event-handling? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to store the possible cursors in a 9-element array and to use the conditions to calculate the index in that array. Something like that:

```
int horzIndex = x < RA ? 0 : x > w-RA ? 2 : 1;
int vertIndex = y < RA ? 0 : y > h-RA ? 2 : 1;
return cursors[horzIndex * 3 + vertIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably do better separating the conditions for `X` and `Y`, something like this pseudocode:

```
const int[] cursorTable = { NW, N, NE, W, M, E, SW, S, SE }

if X < RA, cursor_X = 0
else if X > w-RA, cursor_X = 2
else cursor_X = 1
if Y < RA, cursor_Y = 0
else if Y > h-RA, cursor_Y = 2
else cursor_Y = 1

cursor = cursorTable[cursor_Y * 3 + cursor_Y]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper method with the following signature:

```
private Cursor chooseCursor(int x, int y, int top, int left, int bottom, int right);
```

Then you could call this helper like so. This extracts some of the variables so the helper can focus on the core side-detection logic.

```
setCursor(chooseCursor(
    arg0.getX(),                // x
    arg0.getY(),                // y
    RESCALE_AREA,               // top
    RESCALE_AREA,               // left
    getHeight() - RESCALE_AREA, // bottom
    getWidth () - RESCALE_AREA  // right
));
```

What would this helper method look like, then? Well, you could use some nested conditionals to isolate the tests. When checking horizontally, store -1 if the cursor is to the left, +1 if it's to the right, and 0 if it's in the middle. Like so:

```
int v = (y < top  ? -1 : y > bottom ? +1 : 0);
int h = (x < left ? -1 : x > right  ? +1 : 0);
```

Then the clever part is figuring out how to switch on two variables at once. Each variable holds -1, 0, or +1. You can multiply one by three and add them together to get a value between -4 and +4 inclusive. There are 9 values in that range, and now you can perform one switch to return one of the nine cursors.

That code looks like this:

```
private Cursor chooseCursor(int x, int y, int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
    int v = (y < top  ? -1 : y > bottom ? +1 : 0);
    int h = (x < left ? -1 : x > right  ? +1 : 0);

    int cursor;

    switch (v*3 + h) {
        case -3 + -1: cursor = Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR; break;
        case -3 +  0: cursor = Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR;  break;
        case -3 + +1: cursor = Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR; break;

        case  0 + -1: cursor = Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR;  break;
        case  0 +  0: cursor = Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR;      break;
        case  0 + +1: cursor = Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR;  break;

        case +3 + -1: cursor = Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR; break;
        case +3 +  0: cursor = Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR;  break;
        case +3 + +1: cursor = Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR; break;

        default:
            throw new AssertionError(String.format("impossible v=%s,h=%s", v, h));
    }

    return Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(cursor);
}
```

Comment: This is all untested, so let me know if I made any mistakes. The concept should be sound but I may have made a goof or two.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can suggest is to separately determine horizontal and vertical state. One way to combine it is as @yole did, by using the array. But is's somewhat hardly readable. IMHO, better way is to combine by bit flags and read from table.

```
public class Main {

    static int S = 1;
    static int N = 2;
    static int E = 4;
    static int W = 8;

    static Map<Integer, Integer> cursors = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
        put(S, Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR);
        put(N, Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR);
        put(S | W, Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR);
        //...
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        int delta = 3;
//        int width = 100;
//        int height = 100;
//
//        int x = 100;
//        int y = 200;


        int pos = 0;
        if (x < delta) pos |= W;
        else if (x > width - delta) pos |= E;

        if (y < delta) pos |= N;
        else if (y > height - delta) pos |= S;

        Integer cursor = cursors.get(pos);
        if (cursor != null) {
            //setCursor
        }
    }
}
```